# How to add healthcheck on multiple ports on nginx load balancer?

Tags: nginx, nginx-config

We are using nginx for load balancing our application. There are 4 nodes which need to be load-balanced in round-robin fashion.
The load balancing is working fine.

The **runtime service is listening at port 9001**, which internally redirects to other service on the same node.

So we have defined upstream in nginx.conf, with state file "cluster.state". Following is the excerpt from nginx.conf

```
upstream cluster {
        zone cluster 64k;
        state /var/nginx/state/cluster.state;
}
```

Following is the excerpt in "server" block to route the calls:

```
location /apipattern {
    proxy_set_header Host $host:$server_port;
    proxy_read_timeout 300s;
    proxy_pass http://cluster/;
}
```

Following is the excerpt from cluster.state file (changed FQDNs, but port is correct)

```
server foobar1.com:9001 resolve;
server foobar2.com:9001 resolve;
server foobar3.com:9001 resolve;
server foobar4.com:9001 resolve;
```

The requirement is to put a healtcheck in place (for nodes mentioned in cluster.state).
The healthcheck services (2 services), on these nodes are available on port **8081** and **8082**, with **uri=/healthcheck/isup** (and NOT on 9001)

How do we configure these healthchecks?

Answer (score 0):

you can add multiple health_check directives under location directive with custom port and uri to have compound/multiple monitors for upstream. This is only possible with NGINX plus, which offers active health checking.

```
location /juice {
proxy_set_header Host $host;
proxy_pass http://juice/;
health_check port=800 uri=/custom.html;
health_check port=8081 uri=/hello.html;
}
```